# On if then condition in linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming

I have variables $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and if $a>1$ I want $b=1$ or else $b=0$.
Can this be encoded by linear programming (no integer variables)? Even $b<0.5$ and $b>0.5$ is ok.

Comment: [This](http://benalexkeen.com/linear-programming-with-python-and-pulp-part-6/) may give some idea.

Comment: LP feasible region is convex. Your region for $a,b \in R$ is not. Maybe you are looking for Integer Programming formulation?

Comment: @Eugene can you explain why?

Comment: You changed the question to a different one, in a way that invalidates the existing answer.  That's not very polite to the person who took the time to write an answer to the original question.

Comment: @d.w. ok I will change.

Answer (score 0):

The if then contraints can be written equivalently as

- If $b = 0$, then $a < 1$; and
- If $b = 1$, then $a \geq 1$.

Introduce a large number $M$ and add the following constraints:

$$b(M+1)-M \le a < b(M+1)+1.$$

**EDIT:** I assumed that $b$ is binary. If $a$ is bounded $a\in[L,U)$, we can write the constraints as:

$$b(-L+1)+L \le a < b(U-1)+1.$$

Comment: how large should M be? also this takes $b\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I assumed that $b$ is binary. For $M$, it depends on $a$. See my edits.

Comment: there is an issue i think $a>1$ not $a\geq1$. What if $b=0\iff a\in[0,1]$ and $b=1\iff a>1$?